# bash - sed doesn't replace all semicolons

Tags: bash, sed

I have three variables I write into a text file. For now it is into a variable, because try and error is faster like this. These three variables are produced by the script before and each variable has a column with values in them. Variable one for example looks like this:

```
hour
minute
minute
day
```

I put them together using this code:

```
New_fileloc=$(paste <(echo "$Grabinterval") <(echo "$Filelocation") <(echo "$Time") --delimiters ';' | sed -e 's/^\|$/"/g' -e 's/\;/";"/')
```

At the end I need each line in each column in double quotes and separated by a semicolon. At the moment I am doing that using sed in that one liner. And that works mostly fine. My output looks like this:

```
"hour";"A_path/to/somewhere/;2016-02-10 17:07:00Z"
"minute";"A_path/to/somewhere/;2016-01-29 17:26:20Z"
"minute";"A_path/to/somewhere/;2016-01-29 17:26:20Z"
"day";"A_path/to/somewhere/;2016-01-29 00:07:00Z"
```

The first semicolon gets replaces with ";", but the second one in each line does not. I have no idea why.

Comment: You can try to extend the sed command with the 'g' flag at the end, like this.
sed -e 's/^\|$/"/g' -e 's/\;/";"/g'
This is untested but I guess it might work.

Comment: @g000ze, you know enclosing your code in `\`backticks\`` provides inline formatting for you `:)`

Comment: yep the /g is missing for global

Comment: @David, thank you for the advice, will do next time `:-)`

Comment: Ah, such a little missing part. Thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your last command to sed you are missing a `g`

```
s/\;/";"/g
```

Your original command with `'s/\;/";"/'` will only make one replacement, the first.